# Folder Icon of a document library disappeared

Tags: document-library, folder, file

I have a document library with folders. The folder Icon disappeared.

How can I get it back?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the library view and make sure that the "Type" column is selected in the list of columns to be displayed.